# How to separate setTimeout into two parts in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code with `alert`:

```
input1=function() {
  alert('Hello!');
};

$(function() {
  $('#drop1').click(input1)
});
```

and this code with `setTimeout`:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#drop1').click();
  });
});
```

Both work. But I wanted to leave the second code (`setTimeout`) with the structure of the first, that of `alert`. Something like:

```
input2=function() {
  setTimeout()
};

$(function() {
  $('#drop1').click(input2)
});
```

`HTML` code:

```
<p id='drop1' style='color:#008cba; background-color:#fffF00;'>
  Hi, my name is text 1.
</p>
```

Comment: Rather than having `document.ready` and `setTimeout` callback functions perform `click` operations, which in turn call other callback functions, skip the `click` calls and just have them call the callback that `click` initiates in the first place.

Comment: In addition to fleshing out the `setTimeout()`, you may just want `$('#drop1').click(input2).click();`. This will attach `input2`as a click handler and immediately trigger it. I use this pattern all the time but generally choose to phrase it `$('#drop1').on('click', input2).trigger('click');`.